# PDF generated using Itext is not read by JAWS

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, jaws-screen-reader

I am generating a PDF file using iText 5.5.3. The sample java code which I am using for generating the file is as follows:

```
    Rectangle pageConfig = PageSize.A4;       
    Document doc = new Document(pageConfig);
    try {
          PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, out);
          writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);              
          String country = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
          writer.setTagged();
          doc.addTitle(fileTitle);
          writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.DisplayDocTitle);
          doc.addLanguage(country);        
          writer.createXmpMetadata();
          doc.open();
        for (Iterator iter = this.elements.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Object elt = iter.next();
            //adding the itext high level blocks to the pdf doc
            this.process(doc, elt);
        }            
        doc.close();   
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

The PDF file is generated properly with all the tags, but when I try to read the same pdf using JAWS (screen reader software), it is only announcing the title of the file. It does not reads the content of the file. Can you tell us what are we missing in the above code?

Download the generated pdf here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nhwo5km25gjcm0/License_Mgmt_Report_Domain_INW00005159%20%2810%29.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Hi. Can you please explain a little bit more how do you use JAWS for reading tagged PDF documents? As said here http://doccenter.freedomscientific.com/doccenter/doccenter/rs25c51746a0cc/2012-07-25_pdfwithjaws-l2/02_pdfwithjaws-l2.htm JAWS is applicable for untagged documents mainly and is not needed for reading tagged documents.

Comment: Hi, We are opening the tagged PDF file in Acrobat X professional, we have checked the tags by opening the accessibility panel in Acrobat. Then we start JAWS, it reads the title of the PDF document, but after that it keeps on repeating the title when we press 'tab'. Generally pressing 'tab' should move the next 'readable' section and read it.

Comment: I'm using Acrobat XI and JAWS 16 and everything works fine. I'm not a big expert in JAWS but if I press ["Say All" - INSERT+DOWN ARROW] then document content is reading completely. Also, I'm not sure that JAWS behavior depends on whether PDF document is tagged or not. I tried to run JAWS for untagged documents and it also works. It simply a screen reader which reads everything which is shown on the screen. Which version of JAWS do you use? I tried the latest one which is 16.

Comment: Are you saying that you were able to read the document published at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nhwo5km25gjcm0/License_Mgmt_Report_Domain_INW00005159%20%2810%29.pdf?dl=0?? 
I tried to read the same document using JAWS 15.

Comment: Yes. Here's a voice recording of a part of it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxyruqmg11eudjm/LMR.mp3?dl=0. Is ist what you expected to hear? I'm using Acrobat XI and JAWS 16. Can you try to upgrade to JAWS 16.